# VBA error 13 when deleting multiple cells on "Setup" page of multiple page workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Multiple page workbook, with hidden sheets shown when on the "Setup" sheet, there is a value placed in a cell (Range is F4:F23).  The issue is when you delete the contents of multiple Cells in that range, the pages do not hide, and you get " Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Tried Target.Range
Tried If Not

```
        Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Target.Column = F And Len(Target.Value) > 0 Then

        If Evaluate("Countif(F:F," & Target.Address & ")") > 1 Then
            MsgBox Target.Value & " is a duplicate entry.", vbExclamation, "Duplicate Entry"
            Range(Target.Address).ClearContents

        End If

         End If
```

Then goes on for the code to show or hide, and name worksheet based on value entered. (Which works fine)

Selecting and deleting the contents of 1 cell at a time hides the worksheet and does not return an error, deleting the contents of multiple cells returns an error and does not hide the additional worksheets and remove the name.  I already have a macro created to clear the setup sheet, but can't use it!
I need to be able to clear the contents of multiple cells at a time.

Comment: How is the code working in the first place? `If Target.Column = F And Len(Target.Value) > 0 Then` is not *right*. Even if you had `Target.Column = "F"` you will get an error. One more thing. Since you are working with `Worksheet_Change` and clearing the cells, I highly recommend that you read [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure/13861640#13861640)

Comment: Sorry, in the Original, Target.Column = 6

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was simple to fix, added "On Error Resume Next" and it fixed it!

Comment: "On Error Resume Next" is hardly a solution

Comment: It's the solution I deserve, but not the solution I need.  Yes, I'm a Batman fan.  And yes, I'm new to VBA working on a workbook used for work to make it more efficient.  The VBA coding here is not mine, My coding is limited to a few macros that are assigned to buttons, auto-filling a few cells, and setting the scroll area(Because I actually know how to do those things), I prefer to use formulas in cells whenever possible, because I know how limited I am with VBA....  Watched several classes just to do the macros, and I still get the feeling my head will explode.